# Git-extensions scripts - How to use git log command

Tags: git-extensions

I have checked out a branch in my repository and I want to create a simple log file. I use "Git bash" (Ctrl-G) from Git Extensions and type

```
git log > log.txt
```

which creates the file. 
Now I want to do the same using the "scripts"-functionality of Git Extensions. I tried the following setup in Settings/scripts:

```
Command: git 
Arguments: log > log.txt
```

Running the script I get this error message:

> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" log > log.txt
>   fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working > tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'
>   Done"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using [Git ALiases](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). First apporach was to add "mklog" as an alias to the .git/config file, so that "git mklog" creates the log file.

```
[alias]
mklog = log > log.txt
```

But this results in the same error mentioned in the question. By adding "!git" to the alias-command, it works.

```
mklog = !git log > log.txt
```

In Git Extensions I use the alias in Settings/Scripts:

```
Command: git
Arguments: mklog
```